# Is there any alternative to downloading the Unreal Android tools via CodeWorks installer?

Tags: android, unreal-engine4

I am trying to set up the Android tools for Unreal Editor 4. I am running the Nvidia CodeWorks installer in Engine\Extras\AndroidWorks\Win64. Everything seems to work fine except a couple of the Android packages (Gradle and Java-SDK) refuse to download (my internet connection is fine, and all the other packages download fine).

I assume the server is having issues. Is it possible to download these manually from another source? Is it even possible run in verbose mode so you can see where it is trying to download from?

Comment: Google can't find you download links for Gradle and Java SDK? Asking us to find them for you is off-topic hear, which is clearly stated in the [help/on-topic]. We're also not the *is this site having issues?* help center. If you have questions about an off-site server, contact the maintainers or support team for that server and ask them about that status.

Comment: I am not asking anyone to diagnose the download server. The issue is the CodeWorks installer is a monolithic UI that doesn't tell you anything about what is going on under the hood. If I could work out what actual file/URL those packages correspond to, I'd have a decent chance of find the right file and installing it manually. But without knowing the exact version the chances are it will screw up the install completely.